# Computing a new vector which has deltas from an existing vector

Tags: r

Say I have a vector:

```
c1 <- c(11, 21, 32, 55, 67, 88)
```

Now I want to compute c2 which contains the differences between two successive elements in c1

So the equivalent of:

```
> c2 <- c()
> c2[1] <- 21 - 11
> c2[2] <- 32 - 21
> c2[3] <- 55 - 32
> c2[4] <- 67 - 55
> c2[5] <- 88 - 67
> c2
[1] 10 11 23 12 21
```

What would be elegant way(s) to accomplish this?

Comment: Yeah, this is an easy task because it's a built-in function in R. If it weren't built in, you would probably do something like `c2 <- tail(c1, -1) - head(c1, -1)`.

Comment: yeah that's kind of what I'm doing - lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `diff` function to get the pairwise differences of a vector's elements:

```
(c2 <- diff(c1))
# [1] 10 11 23 12 21
```

<sup>Apologies for the late answer; I noticed this was only answered (by me) in the comments, so I wanted to get it closed up.</sup>