# c++ computing a new vector which has deltas from an existing vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I'm working on learning C++ STL algorithms. I need help trying to find a function to create a vector of deltas from values in an existing vector. In other words:

- delta0 = abs(original1 - original0)
- delta1 = abs(original2 - original1)
- and so on.

I'm looking for something concise, like R's "diff" function mentioned here:
 [computing a new vector which has deltas from an existing vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542872/computing-a-new-vector-which-has-deltas-from-an-existing-vector)

I found the transform function but it seemed to operate on a single element at a time. It didn't seem to allow parameters of iterator in the function supplied to transform so I was limited to the current element only. I'm trying to learn STL algorithms so I don't really need any libraries that may have "diff" implemented. I would just like to see a way to use STL functions to solve this if there is a concise way I'm not aware of.

Here is an example with the section in question commented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> delta;

    //---------------------------------------
    // way to do this with STL algorithms?
    for (auto i = v.begin()+1; i != v.end(); i++) {
        delta.push_back(abs(*i - *(i - 1)));
    }
    //---------------------------------------
    for (int i : delta) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `diff` function that i know of, what is wrong with looping over it the way you have done? It is likely that this is how `r` does it anyway. Do you need more speed or something?

Comment: The algorithm you're speculating about *almost* matches [`std::adjacent_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference).  This function only differs in that the first result is the first element of your collection, unaltered.

Comment: It is just a learning exercise. It seemed like transform was close so I had a feeling I was missing something.

Comment: yeah, adjacent_difference looks like a good one too. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::transform(std::next(v.begin()), v.end(),
               v.begin(), delta.begin(),
               [](int a, int b){ return std::abs(a - b); });
```

You simply missed the second version of `transform`. Take a look at it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

See that code in action [online](http://cpp.sh/3ztzh)!